# C++ line.exe has stopped working

Tags: c++

I make some program in C++ which in matrix finds longest horizontal line of 0s.
In first line I input n and m (rows and columns in matrix array a), and later array. Main problem is when I insert first line (all correct with it) the program stops with error -1073741510, line.exe has stopped working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n, m;

    int a[n][m];

    int i,j,k;

    for (i=0;i<n;i=i+1){
        for(j=0;j<m;j=j+1){
            int temp;
            cin >> temp;
            a[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }

    int max;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(a[i][j]==0){
                for(k=j+1;k<m;k++){
                    if(a[i][k]==0){
                        max++;
                    }else{break;}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << max;

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for big amount of for loops, I don't know better way of solving problem.

Answer (score 1):

To read both numbers `n` and `m` use:

```
cin >> n >> m;
```

Otherwise, as you have `cin >> n, m;` it is equivalent with

```
cin >> n;
m; // This has no effect
```

For a solution to the correct operation of your algorithm, try this:

```
int maxZeros = 0;
int lineContainingMaxZeros = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int countZero = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] == 0)
            countZero++;
    }
    if (countZero > maxZeros) {
        maxZeros = countZero;
        lineContainingMaxZeros = i;
    }
}
cout << "Line: " << lineContainingMaxZeros << " containing " << maxZeros << " zeros";
```

Comment: I have correct that, program now run correctly, but result is wrong.

Comment: You have not initialized `max`. And you're not using spaces like I told you to, which is irritating.

Comment: I now initialized max, but result is again wrong. P.S. @LogicStuff I don't know how you think to use spaces, where?

Comment: Like this: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`, secondly, declare `i, j, k` for every loop: `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, remove local declarations.

Comment: To get the correct result wasn't the part of the question. I have no idea what you want your program to do.

Comment: @LogicStuff Program needs to find longest 0s horisontal line. Example 101, 010, 001. It make grid 3*3. And longest line is 2, in third matrix row(001)

Comment: If that's the case, I can tell you that there's not enough logic in your code to calculate that.